# How to have scrollable 2d html elements over a vr background?

Tags: html, css, aframe, virtual-reality

So I'm looking to implement a 360 image as a background to an already existing html file. I've used z-index to put the scene behind the other elements but if I do this it means that I cannot scroll the 2d content even thought the background works perfectly.

If I make the scene embedded, this means that I can scroll the content but the scene does not load.

Does anyone know how I can implement this, or make an embedded scene fullscreen possibly?

The scene looks like this:

```
<a-scene embedded allowfullscreen="yes" allowvr="yes">
    <a-sky src="puydesancy.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>

    <a-text font="kelsonsans" value="WELCOME TO WABIYOLAND" width="6" position="-2.5 0.25 -1.5" rotation="0 15 0"></a-text>
 </a-scene>
```

The css is as follows, with the html having no background:

```
a-scene embedded {
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It should be noted that this is specifically for mobile, and the vr is affected by the motion of the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't scroll the site because the scene is intercepting the events, you can just place an empty div in front of the scene.

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<a-scene>
  ...
```

**CSS**

```
div {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%
}
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/fjop9qxd/3/).